# Login with Hibernate and store username logged

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I'm developing a simple project cloud in which a registered user after login can download and upload files.
I'm developing with Eclipse Java EE, JSF and Hibernate.
In my project I can sign in to the user and if the data are correct I open the user menu but can not figure out where to store the information about the user logged. It is not clear so the concept of session. I've read several things about Hibernate and the session but I do not understand yet. I need to keep at least the username of the user currently logged in, use what object? and where?. Could you help me? thanks

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Login {

private String userId;
private String password;

public Login() {}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String loginUser (){
    SessionHandler s = new SessionHandler();
    Session sessione = s.getDb();
    sessione.beginTransaction();
    Query query = sessione.createQuery( "Select password from Utenti where username= :id" );
    System.out.println("Qui lo prende: " + this.getUserId());
    query.setParameter("id", userId);
    System.out.println("tag debug");
    List<Utenti> res= query.list();
    if(password.equals(res.get(0))){
        this.setUserId(userId);
        return "first";

    }
    else
        return "noaccess";
}
```

I need to use userid in TreeBean. This is my TreeBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TreeBean {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{login.userId}")
private String user;

private TreeNode root;
private TreeNode selectedNode;
private Session db;

public Session getDb() {
    return db;
}

public void setDb(Session db) {
    this.db = db;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getUser(){
    return user;
}

public TreeBean() {  
    root=new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
    System.out.println("Prova"+ user);
    recursive(0, root);

}
```

In .xhtml files can read userid without any problems. Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a ManagedBean of session scope. On login, you set the user object (that you got from DB) in that ManagedBean. And then, you will be able to access it through all the application.

Alternative way, is to set the user object directly in session:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
```

And then:

```
sessionMap.put("attributeName", whateverYouWantToSaveInSession);
```

But I would choose the first approach.

Comment: I already have a managed bean related to login.jsf when I select the query in the database for matching with the entered password. Following the first approach I have to create another bean or use what I have?

Comment: It's up to you to choose. Personally, I use a separate session managed bean, in which I save all session variables (like logged in user)

Comment: I ask you one last thing. Now I have two beans, one in which I keep the info session and one that implements the login form. I have another bean that builds the user menu. How am I going to call the bean and its value InfoSession about the authenticated user in the bean menu?

Comment: if you want to use the SessionInfo bean in another managed bean, you ca just inject it. It depends on whether you are using annotations or xml how to inject (just google it). In xhtml, you just access it as any other managed bean property.

Comment: Why not just putting it in `ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`? You should try to avoid `javax.servlet.*` imports in your JSF backing beans as much as possible.

Comment: By the way, BalusC, regarding memory usage and performance, which one would you suggest ? Using session scoped managed bean to store session variables or using the sessionMap in ExternalContext

Comment: I'm trying with the managed property but I do not understand why is null, while in the related file .xhtml is not null.
There are no errors at compile time and the injection appears to be correct, but the value of the managed property is null.

Comment: can you post your code please, whether here (edit your question) or in another question. It may be that you've got some errors in your logic

Comment: I think, since TreeBean is session scoped, it's instantiated before login method is called, in that time, #{login.userId} is null (I mean the userId)

Comment: ok, I understand. It's possible and what I do for resolve this? sorry, but I am a newbie

Comment: First thing, avoid to make all your managed beans as session scoped. (This will solve it, but it's not the real solution). If you want to update the TreeBean after it's created, you can get it from context and set it's attribute when login() method gets called.

Comment: I tried to do Session Scoped for loginBean and request scoped for treeBean but don't work, login.userId is still null

Comment: I solved with sessionMap but didactically interesting to see how the beans are initialized in first approach. Thanks!