# JSF/Primefaces SelectedOneRadio: value is null

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Primefaces' SelectOneRadio that extend standard SelectOneRadio.
My problem is that when I select the option that I want download this or not saved or is lost. I enclose the code. Why does this happen? Thanks

This is my Bean for download:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DownloadFile {

private StreamedContent file;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{selecter.selectedRadio}")
private Files selectedRadio;

//all getters/setters methods
....
....


public DownloadFile() throws IOException {          
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
    response.reset(); // Some JSF component library or some Filter might have set some headers in the buffer beforehand. We want to get rid of them, else it may collide.
    response.setContentType("application/xml"); // Check http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp for all types. Use if necessary ServletContext#getMimeType() for auto-detection based on filename.
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"immagine.jpg\""); 

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        //Qui va sostituita la risorsa con pathname+/selectedRadio (pathname la otterremo da una query)
        System.out.println("Prova::" + selectedRadio);
        //String s= selectedRadio.getPathname()+"/"+selectedRadio.getNome();
        input = new BufferedInputStream(externalContext.getResourceAsStream("/downloaded_optimus.jpg"));
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
        for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }

    facesContext.responseComplete(); // Important! Else JSF will attempt to render the response which obviously will fail since it's already written with a file and closed.
    }
}
```

This is my bean for selecter:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Selecter {
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{sessionHandler.db}")
private Session db;
private List<Files> res= new ArrayList<Files>();
private Files selectedRadio;
//all getters/setters methods ....

 @PostConstruct
 public void init(){
     db.beginTransaction();
     ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
     Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
     Query query = db.createQuery( "from Utenti where username= :name" );
     query.setParameter("name", (String)(sessionMap.get("username")));
     List<Utenti>user= query.list();

     for(Utenti a : user){
        Iterator<Files> it = a.getFileses().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            res.add( it.next());
        }
     }
     db.getTransaction().commit();
 }
```

}

and this is my file .xhtml

```
h2>Seleziona dall'elenco il file che vuoi scaricare</h2>
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p:outputPanel id="customPanel">  
    <p:selectOneRadio id = "radioID" value="#{selecter.selectedRadio}" layout="pageDirection" >
       <f:selectItems value="#{selecter.res}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.nome}"  itemValue="#{item}" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">  
        <p:graphicImage value="/design/ajax_loading_bar.gif" />  
    </p:dialog>  
    <br></br>       
    <br></br>

    <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false" immediate="true"
    icon="ui-icon-arrowthichk-s">  
        <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadFile.file}" />  
    </p:commandButton>  


</p:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `immediate="true"` attribute on the command component will only process input components which *also* have this attribute set. Your radio button input component doesn't have it and is therefore ignored during processing of the form submit.

Further, this construct will fail if `#{downloadFile}` managed bean is been created and instantiated *before* the update model values phase (i.e. before the `#{selecter.selectedRadio}` is been set by JSF).

Replace

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{selecter.selectedRadio}")
private Files selectedRadio;
```

by

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{selecter}")
private Selecter selecter;
```

and access the `selectedRadio` in the action method instead.

Comment: How can I manage and solve this problem of creation and initialization of the Bean that takes place before the values ​​are assigned? 
Here I had the same problem and I followed the second approach that you have suggested because they are not able to solve the first.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633818/login-with-hibernate-and-store-username-logged

Comment: I'm not sure why you see it as a problem. How is it in "plain Java" ever possible to invoke methods on an instance before it's constructed?

Comment: @BalusC: Am I right to say that his code would work if he doesn't call his `downloadFile` managed bean anywhere above the `selecter`?

Comment: @BalusC: Of course not, it is not possible invoke methods on an instance before it's constructed. But how do you see this problem and what I linked to you in the previous comment seem very similar. In both cases, a bean is initialized before you have all the necessary data. And I do not think you understand how to properly fix.

Comment: @BalusC: I tried to do the replacement that you have suggested but it does not work the same. It is always null.

Comment: If I delete the attribute immediate=true does not gives me the exception, but there is an error in the page .jsf (Conversion Error setting value ...  for 'null Converter'.)

Comment: Apparently you haven't registered a converter for `Files` class.