# How to make RESTFUL navigation in JSF 2 ?

Tags: jsf

I have a table where I list some actors.. This page is actor.xhtml. Here is the relavent part:

```
<p:dataTable id="allActors" var="actor" value="#{actorTableBackingBean.allActors}">
                <p:column headerText="Actor Name" sortBy="#{actor.firstName}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{actor.firstName}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Actor Detail">
                    <h:link value="Go to actor detail" outcome="actorDetail?actorId=#{actor.actorId}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

So when I click link Go To Actor Detail in the table, I am successfully navigated to: actorDetail.xhtml?actorId=1

And here is actorDetail.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition template="../maintemp.xhtml">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="actorId" value="#{actorDetailBackingBean.actorId}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <ui:define name="mainarea">

        <div class="well" style="padding: 15px" >
            <h3>Actor Detail</h3>
        </div>
        #{actorDetailBackingBean.actorWith().firstName}
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And here is my ActorDetailBackingBean.java :

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ActorDetailBackingBean extends BasePage {

    @Inject
    ActorDao actorDao;

    @Inject
    Actor actor;

    private int actorId;

    public int getActorId() {
        return actorId;
    }

    public void setActorId(int actorId) {
        this.actorId = actorId;
    }

    public Actor actorWith(){
        actor = actorDao.getWithId(actorId);
        return actor;
    }
}
```

But this returns zero data.. So the detail is not loaded. actorDao.getWithId is called with parameter 0.

What is it that I am missing?

Also a bonus question:

How would I do this with a POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

Pass a String to the bean, not an int. Now it works!

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi can you please detail?

Comment: From your question's title, I think you want that `actorId` appears in the URL. And then, you asked about how to make it in a POST way. Am I right ?

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi No, the second way I do not want it to appear in the URL. I want ( I guess ) a h:commandLink but I could not make it work..

Comment: This is what I have tried but it does not work: <p:column headerText="Actor Detail">
                    <h:commandLink value="Go to Actor Detail" action="#{actorTableBackingBean.returnActorrrDetail(actor)}" />
                </p:column>

Comment: yes of course, since your View/Request scoped bean will be re-created.

Comment: This answer from BalusC would help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701590/passing-parameters-between-managed-beans-with-request-scope

Comment: A good way, would be to put the Actor object (or only its id) in the session, and then in the `actorWith` method you retrieve it

Comment: Can you provide a detailed answer?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633818/login-with-hibernate-and-store-username-logged/15634393#15634393